# Linear Algebra - Subspaces of $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone please explain why all 4 statements are not a subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$. I appreciate all answers.
$$$$
How many of the following are subspaces of $\mathbb{R^n}$

$\bullet$ the solution set of a linear system of $m$ equations in $n$ unknowns, with $m < n$

$\bullet$ the solution set of a linear system of $m$ equations in $n$ unknowns, with $m = n$

$\bullet$ the solution set of a linear system of $m$ equations in $n$ unknowns, with $m \leq n$

$\bullet$ the solution set of a linear system of $m$ equations in $n$ unknowns, with $m > n$

Comment: Hint or question: are the equations homogenous? That is, are they linear combinations of the unknowns that sum to $0$?

Comment: They did not specify in the question.

Comment: If I had to answer the question I would write "If the equations are homogeneous then ... but if they are not then ... because ...". I hope you can fill in the blanks.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker I agree, but a small recall is maybe useful: "homogeneous" (an adjective which is not universaly known or understood by students, depending also on the educational systems) means "with RHS (where the constants are situated) identically O".

Comment: @JeanMarie I recalled the definition in my first comment.